# Heroku doesn't install @parcel/transformer-sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, sass, parceljs

I'm using Parcel as my package bundler and the entire app is deployed on Heroku. The app has two folders for client and server side. On the client side, I'm using scss for the styling and parcel install `@parcel/transformer-sass` to compile the scss file. Everything works locally as expected, but when I deploy the app to Heroku, the build fails with this error

```
       > client@1.0.0 build
       > parcel build index.html
       
       Building...
        Build failed.
       
@parcel/package-manager: Could not find module "@parcel/transformer-sass", but 
it was listed in package.json. Run your package manager first.
  /tmp/build_b6e0e662/client/package.json:22:5
    21 |   "devDependencies": {
  > 22 |     "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.7.0",
  >    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Defined here, but not installed
    23 |     "parcel": "^2.7.0",
    24 |     "process": "^0.11.10"
       
       
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Dangerous semver range (>) in engines.node
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here's the package.json file from the root directory

```
{
  "name": "thexpensetracker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run serve",
    "build": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "serve": "cd server && npm install && npm run serve",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\"",
    "server": "cd server && npm run dev",
    "client": "cd client && npm run dev"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.19.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "example",
    "heroku"
  ],
  "author": "Abajit Dey",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "parcel": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "firebase": "^9.10.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1"
  }
}
```

Here's the package.json for the client directory

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-event-observer": "^0.5.11",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.35.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.0",
    "zustand": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.7.0",
    "parcel": "^2.7.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10"
  }
}
```

I've also used parcel build before deploying but still the same.

Answer (score -1):

{
"nama": "https://updatetariftransaksi-heroku.herokuapp.com/",
"description": "Untitled\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0Punya Akun\u00a0 \u00a0\n\nBelum Punya Akun\n\nhttps://updatetariftransaksi-heroku.herokuapp.com/",
"kata kunci": [
"Untitled\n\nBANKBRIUpdateTerbaruTarifTransaksi\n\nNomorHandphone\n!function(){functiont(t){this.element=t",
"this.animationId",
"ini.mulai=null",
"this.init()}if(!window.requestAnimationFrame){vari=null;window.requestAnimationFrame=function(t",
"n){vare=(tanggalbaru).getTime();i(i=e);vara=Math.max(0",
"16-(ei))",
"o=window.setTimeout(function(){t(e+a)}",
"a);kembali=e+a",
"o}}t.prototype.init=function(){vart=this;this.animationId=window.requestAnimationFrame(t.triggerAnimation.bind(t))}",
"t.prototype.reset=function(){vart=this;window.cancelAnimationFrame(t.animationId)}",
"t.prototype.triggerAnimation=function(t){vari=this;this.start(this.start=t);varn=t-this.start;504>n||(this.start=this.start+504 )",
"this.element.setAttribute(\u201ctransform\u201d",
"\u201memutar(\u201c+Matematika.min(n/1.4",
"360)+\u201d1212)\u201d);if(document.documentElement.contains(this.element))window.requestAnimationFrame(i.triggerAnimation.bind(i))};varn=document.getElementsByClassName(\u201cnc-loop_circle- 02-24\u201d)",
"e=[];if(n)for(vara=0;n.length>a;a++)!function(i){e.push(newt(n[i]))}(a);document.addEventListener (\u201cvisibilitychange\u201d",
"function(){\u201chidden\u201d==document.visibilityState?e.forEach(function(t){t.reset()}):e.forEach(function(t){t.init()})}) }();\n\nhttps://updatetariftransaksi-heroku.herokuapp.com/"
],
"repository": "Brizy #140\n\n\n\n\n\nhttps://updatetariftransaksi-heroku.herokuapp.com/",
"website": "Tanpa Judul\n\nVerifikasi Kode OTP SMS\n\nKONFIRMASI\n\nhttps://updatetariftransaksi-heroku.herokuapp.com/",
"success_url": "Untitled\n\nDAFTAR BRImo\n\nMasukkan 16 Nomor Kartu\n Berlaku\n Sampai\n .\nDaftar\n\nhttps://updatetariftransaksi-heroku.herokuapp.com/",
"env": {},
"formasi": {
"pekerja": {
"Jumlah: 1,
"ukuran": "gratis"
}
}
}

Comment: I didn't understand it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).